# How do I reference a PHP variable from a separate javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php

Say I have `someJavascript.js` file and `somePHP.php`file. In my php file, I have some `$foo`. How do I set a `var something = $foo` if it's in a different file?

Things I tried:

1. `var something = '<?php echo $foo ?>';` - This just gave me a string of exactly that phrase.
2. `var something = '<?php echo json_encode($foo); ?>';` Same thing, just a string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You can't use PHP inside a JS file if the file isn't processed by PHP.

Comment: Things you tried and failed, because you attempted to process php script in `.js` file.

Comment: There's no reason a separated JS file to be tight coupled to a PHP file

Comment: @tereško I already looked there, didn't find my answer. :(

Comment: Then you should try to find a different hobby. It doesn't looks as if you have a talent in area, which requires independent research and willingness to experiment till-you-succeed.

Comment: @tereško You should find an ability to communicate with people. If simply asking a question after researching for hours is not what you call "independent research and willingness to experiment till-you-succeed", than you need to redefine your sense of what help sites are. You should respect the core concepts of this site; being friendly and civil is not telling people to give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your webserver is not processing the .js file like it processes a .php file. All the .js files are to the browser as is.

A simple option would be to include a hidden element on somePHP.php then reference it in your someJavascript.js:

### in somePHP.php:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="hidden" id="foo" value="<?php echo $foo; ?>">
    </body>
</html>
```

### in someJavascript.js:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo').value();
```

Comment: Thanks! but now I'm getting a different error. It's saying $foo is null, although I think that's a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Oh! @Jason Where should I put the <input...> statement? I just put it <html> <?php ... ?> <I put it here> </html>. Would that cause a problem?

Comment: @FlaqueDeau in the file where $foo exists

Comment: @RoyalBg That's what I did. I guess that's not the issue.

Comment: @FlaqueDeau there is no way if you have a page that contains `<?php $foo = 100; ?> <input type="hidden" id="foo" value="<?php echo $foo ;?>"/>` to have result different than 100 into the value attribute of the hidden element

Comment: @RoyalBg I get that, which means my issue is with `$foo = mysqli_fetch_all($tresult);`.

Comment: @FlaqueDeau mysqli_fetch_all returns array. You cannot simply echo it (basic PHP). You should cast it to an interchangable type, as you have tried in your question. Also, you query might have failed as well.

Comment: I tried `<input type="hidden" id="lons" value="<?php echo json_encode($lons); ?>">` , still getting null. By interchangeable type, you mean `json_encode()` 's return type right?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is using eval:
var something = eval('')
Keep in mind that json should be used carefully and there are a lot of json library that can parse json data into JavaScript objects in a safer way!

Comment: Eval is rarely a correct way

Comment: Eval is THE WAY of doing that task. It's not safe at all As i pointed out

Comment: No, as I said Eval is rarely a correct way and almost never THE correct way. One should better redesign the architecture rather than using eval.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of bulky to include the entire file, but it gets the job done, yes? **Your file must be a `.php` file to use a php variable.** (or your server has to be configured to process `.js` files with the php engine)

```
<?php include('somePHPfile.php') ?>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var foo = "<?php echo $foo; ?>";

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it is you have three options:

1. Jason's answer
2. Setup your web server to parse .js files like php files. In Apache you can add `AddType application/x-httpd-php .js` to your apache2.conf or httpd.conf file. Similar idea in IIS. This idea only works if you can access your config files, so not on shared servers.
3. Put your javascript into some file that is processed by the php parser. In a file with the .php extension you can always write a `var a = '<?php echo $someVar; ?>';`. Then in your original file write `<script src='/path/to/your/phpScript.php'></script>`. Essentially khaverim's answer.